# Die Arbeiten werden auf Nachweis ausgeführt

Tags: translation, idiom, german-to-english

> Die Arbeiten werden auf Nachweis ausgeführt

Trying to translate a subcontractor quotation, I found this line, which appears to be some sort of generic term or condition but also a bit of an idiom which doesn’t have an obvious direct translation that makes sense in English.

Has anyone seen this before and/or could please help me put it into a logical English sentence?

Comment: While I do not expect you to find this phrase in a dictionary, can you please elaborate how you understand it. This would greatly improve your question, as it allows us to directly address your problems and better see the difficulties of the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Auf Nachweis* means that the (sub-)contractor keeps tracks of all work that was done (-> *[Arbeitsnachweis](http://image.channeladvisor.de/105116/59bf4e86d8879c50a7052210174fef86.jpg)*, or colloquially *Stundenzettel*), including time, executed tasks, used machinery (optional) and time to drive to building site, which is signed and supplied to the customer to be countersigned. This is the basis for the subsequent billing - basically hourly rate in English.

Another model of billing would be a fixed rate (*Festpreis*), where the contractor "wins" if he is faster than expected and "looses" when the work proves to be more time-consuming than estimated at the beginning.

Comment: I've gone for "The work will be carried out at hourly rates"